# Php code that returns an array with filenames of files which contains a string

Tags: php, json

Im trying to make a Php file that receives nothing and checks every file on the folder, searching for a string inside them. it echos a array of filenames that have the string inside. Any way to do it, possibly with low memory usage?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: This one is easily searched on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve something like this, I recommend you read about the [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) class, [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), and about [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) in PHP.

Here is an example of how you can read the contents of a a given directory ($dir) and use [strstr](http://php.net/strstr) to search for a specific string occurrence in each file's contents ($contents):

```
<?php

$dir = '.';

if (substr($dir, -1) !== '/') {
    $dir .= '/';
}

$matchedFiles = [];

$dirIterator = new \DirectoryIterator($dir);

foreach ($dirIterator as $item) {
    if ($item->isDot() || $item->isDir()) {
        continue;
    }

    $file = realpath($dir . $item->getFilename());

    // Skip this PHP file.
    if ($file === __FILE__) {
        continue;
    }

    $contents = file_get_contents($file);

    // Seach $contents for what you're looking for.
    if (strstr($contents, 'this is what I am looking for')) {
        echo 'Found something in ' . $file . PHP_EOL;
        $matchedFiles[] = $file;
    }
}

var_dump($matchedFiles);
```

There is some extra code in this example (adding a trailing slash to $dir, skipping dot files and directories, skipping itself, etc.) that I encourage you to read and learn about.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$folderPath = '/htdocs/stock/tae';
$searchString = 'php';
$cmd = "grep -r '$searchString' $folderPath";
$output = array();
$files = array();
$res = exec($cmd, $output);
foreach ($output as $line) {
    $files[] = substr($line, 0, strpos($line, ':'));
}
print_r($files);
```